# Java Service - SOAP Responses return always NULL to .NET

Tags: java, .net, xml, soap, xsd

I have an SOAP 1.1 Service developed with Spring Boot in Java which responses without any problems to any of my requests and deliver a valid SOAP-response.

Now the problem is as soon as I add this service as Service Reference to any .NET/C# project the reference gets created and I can send requests but the response (Which get definitely sent from my SOAP-Service) cant be mapped back and the object in my .NET application is always null.

I already found out what the problem might be but I don't know exactly how (of if it is even possible like this) to change my xsd/wsdl to generate all the sources correctly.

First of all here is my .xsd from my Java Spring Boot project for the generation of the WSDL & Service Reference:

Here is the code from the generated Service Reference from Visual Studio in a C# project:

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute([NAMESPACE]/processing", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("processingResponse", Namespace="http://[NAMESPACE]/base", IsNullable=true)]
public processingResponse processing([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://[NAMESPACE]/base", IsNullable=true)] processingRequest processingRequest) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("processing", new object[] {
        processingRequest});
    return ((processingResponse)(results[0]));
}
```

I found out if I change the following line

```
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("processingResponse", Namespace="http://[NAMESPACE]", IsNullable=true)]
```

and add "Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified":

```
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("processingResponse", Namespace="http://[NAMESPACE]", IsNullable=true, Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
```

The response gets mapped correctly to my Object and it seem to work like this without any problems at the moment.

The problem is that I want to change my .xsd to generate these sources correctly from the start - I already tried to add Form=Unqualified to the "AppDataDataResult" element inside the "processingResponse" complexType but it doesnt work.

Adding this property directly to the processingResponse Element isn't working either cause it's not possible cause the <xs:element/> is one level beneath the schema definition/tag.

I havent found any concrete solution to this problem cause it seems to be very specific with the Spring Boot Framework Java, and the generation of the wsdl.

I hope someone can help me with this problem cause it doesnt seem to be a big one (Its "only" a attribute which needs to get added during the generation of the sources) but I cant seem to find a solution to this. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Problem and it was a really simple fix for this Issue - In my Spring Boot Project I was returning JAXBElements and a Parameter for the response is the "QName" which indicates the Object of the Response. The Problem here was that the SOAP-Response did not have the relevant Namespace to identify the Object during the generation of Sources in .NET. So I added the correct Namespace-URI to the QName-Object and now the objects gets resolved and returns the correct responses:

```
final QName qname = new QName(NAMESPACE_URI, "processingResponse");
return new JAXBElement<>(qname, ProcessingResponse.class, processingResponse);
```

In the end it was a pretty stupid/simple problem but I tried everything else but havent tried to most obvious/easiest.